# Woocommerce Change Order Status to Processing when Sending Contact Form 7

Tags: function, woocommerce

I use Contact Form 7 for customers to upload proof of payment, then redirect them to a Thank You Page with order_id param, using URL Params plugin (shortcode below). In the head I inserted (theme feature, no messing with original head files):

```
<?php
    do_action('woocustom_change_orderstatus', [urlparam param="order_id"]);
?>
```

The function goes like this:

```
function fx_changewoostatus($order_id){
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $order->update_status('wc-processing');
}
```

The order is not updating though. It is still on hold.

Comment: `$order->update_status('processing');` - Mention the status without prefix `wc-`

Comment: Hi there. It still won't change the order status. Any suggestion?